# How can i Paste to Different Row after Getting search Results

Tags: excel, vba

I need help on how can i paste a result on Column "G" Row "2" after searching an entire Column A for the word "Country Code: " . Below is my Code for the process.

Currently My Code is able to copy the specific word and paste it .
But it only paste on Column A which overlap the existing data.

```
 Sub SearchForString()

   Dim LSearchRow As Integer
   Dim LCopyToRow As Integer
   Dim LCopytoColumn As String


   'On Error GoTo Err_Execute

   'Start search in row 1
    LSearchRow = 1

   'Start copying data to column G in Database
    LCopytoColumn = 7

   'Start copying data to row 2 in Database and Loop results
    LCopyToRow = 2


   While Len(Range("A" & CStr(LSearchRow)).Value) > 0

          'If value in column E = "Mail Box", copy entire row to Sheet2
           If InStr(1, Range("A" & CStr(LSearchRow)).Value, "Country Code:") > 0 Then

         'Select row in Sheet1 to copy
          Rows(CStr(LSearchRow) & ":" & CStr(LSearchRow)).Select
          Selection.Copy

          'Paste row into G2 in next row
           Range("G2").Select
          'Columns(CStr(LCopytoColumn) & ":" & CStr(LCopytoColumn)).Select
           Rows(CStr(LCopyToRow) & ":" & CStr(LCopyToRow)).Select
           ActiveSheet.Paste


           'Move counter to next row
            LCopyToRow = LCopyToRow + 1

           'Go back to Database to continue searching
           Sheets("Database").Select

        End If

        LSearchRow = LSearchRow + 1

   Wend

   'Position on cell G2
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Range("G2").Select

    MsgBox "All matching data has been copied."

   Exit Sub

'Err_Execute:
'   MsgBox "An error occurred."

 End Sub
```

Comment: You are confusing columns, rows and cells as well as copy and paste. Could you please clean your question of such confusions? "G2" is a cell, not a column. "A" designates a column, not a row. "Copy on column A" might mean "copy from column A" but you seem to mean "paste to column A" (whatever "column A" might mean). Usually one doesn't paste to a row or column, however, but to a cell. If you paste a row array to A2 VBA will use the cells to the right of A2 for any additional data. If you paste a column array to A2 the result will be arranged vertically.

Comment: Hi , Thank you for you feedback i have realized that my wording is very confusing and have edited to be more understandable. With that , How can i paste my search result from Column A and Paste it on Column G row 2. The macro is only able to paste on Column A Row 2. Thank you again

Comment: **[1.]** It is still confusing. Is 'G2' in the same sheet as 'A'? If yes, then why copy the row instead of the value? **[2.]** If you just want the value to reflect in `G2` if it exists in Col A, then why VBA? A simple formula can get that value into `G2`

Comment: [1.] Yes , G2 is still in the same sheet as A. From my practice, I would like the macro to go through the whole A and find any matching string , copy the matched string and paste on Column G starting at Cell G2 until there is no more matching string.

[2.] This is one part of the value that i would want to show. As in Col A there would be different kind of value within it such as Name , Age and so on. I would like to create a macro that would able to catch these string in a short period of time

Answer (score 0):

Using Variant Array is simple and fast.

```
Sub test()
    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    Dim toWs As Worksheet
    Dim vDB, vR()
    Dim i As Long, n As Long, c As Integer
    Dim j As Integer

    Set Ws = Sheets("yoursheetname")
    Set toWs = Sheets("Database")

    vDB = Ws.UsedRange
    c = UBound(vDB, 2)
    For i = 1 To UBound(vDB, 1)
        If InStr(vDB(i, 1), "Country Code:") Then
            n = n + 1
            ReDim Preserve vR(1 To c, 1 To n)
            For j = 1 To c
                vR(j, n) = vDB(i, j)
            Next j
        End If
    Next i
    toWs.Range("g2").Resize(n, c) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(vR)
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Dy Lee , Thank you for your answer with the sample code. But may i ask how does it work as i am still learning VBA . Furthermore , How can I extract a different string such as "Example: " and put it on the next Column "H"